# « Être heureux dans les yeux …», qu'est-ce que ça signifie, exactement ?

Tags: sens

Il y a une belle chanson de Françoise Hardy, « Parlez-moi de lui ». Le sujet de la chanson c'est la séparation. Un ami absent n'écrit plus à une femme qui est amoureuse de lui, elle chante, elle veut tout savoir au sujet de lui ; peut-être aime-t-il une autre femme présentement, suggère l'héroïne de la chanson. Je cite un extrait :

> Alors dites-moi 
>   Si elle est jolie 
>   Plus jolie que moi 
>   Et lui dans ses yeux 
>   Était-il heureux?

Dans les yeux de qui est-il heureux, selon sa conjecture ? Et qu'est-ce que ça signifie, « dans les yeux » ? Une opinion ? Quelque chose d'autre ?

Merci beaucoup !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Elle demande si le bonheur de son ami était visible « dans ses yeux » (ceux de son ami).

Étant sous-entendu que si une personne est heureuse, cela se voit dans ses yeux.